# Convert from C# function to JavaScript function

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a function in c# that used to manipulate the string, It works well while I used in C#. Now I want to convert this function to use in JavaScript. This is the function in C#:

```
 public static string TrimString(string str, int lenght)
 {
        string _str = str;

        int _iAdditionalLenght = 0;

        for (int i = lenght; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_str.Substring(i, 1) == " ")
                break;

            _iAdditionalLenght++;
        }

        return str.Substring(0, str.Length < (lenght + _iAdditionalLenght) ? str.Length : (lenght + _iAdditionalLenght));

 }
```

I converted it to javascript :

```
function TrimString(str, lengthStr) { //this is my testing 4
     var _str = str;
     var _iAdditionalLenght = 0;
     for (var i = lengthStr; i < str.length; i++) {
       if (_str.substring(i, 1) == " ")
           break;
       _iAdditionalLenght++;
     }

     return str.substring(0, str.length < (lengthStr + _iAdditionalLenght) ? str.length : (lengthStr + _iAdditionalLenght));
 }
```

But the javascript doesn't work.

Could anyone tell me, how could I do it in JavaScript function?

Comment: What doesn't work about the javascript version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substring differs between C# & javascript

Eg., strInput = "0123456789"

## In C#  ==> Substring(int startIndex, int length)

```
     strInput.SubString(2,3) == will output ==> "234"
```

## In Javascript ==> substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)

```
     strInput.substring(2,3) == will output ==> "2"
```

instread try to use

```
     strInput.substr(2,3) == will output ==> "234"
```

Note :

in javscript

```
     substring(Start character position, End Character position) 

     substr(Start character position, length of Character)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the differences in the way `substring` works in JavaScript and C#. In C# it is the number of characters that should be extracted and in JS it is the index where to stop extraction.